# Postgresql - Counting Elements of a 2D JSON array

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgresql JSON 2D array column containing string terms, e.g.:

**Input**

```
[["edwards", "block", "row"], ["edwards"], ["block"]]
```

Is it possible to compute the occurrence of each term purely in Postgresql? e.g.:

**Output**

```
Terms,                        Occur
["edwards", "block", "row"]   [2,2,1]
```

(Or in some similar format). Or would I have to compute the occurrences using a programming language?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
select array_to_json(array(
    select json_array_length(a.value)
    from json_array_elements('[["edwards", "block", "row"], ["edwards"], ["block"]]'::json) a
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out eventually. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(t), t
FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(json->'named_entities') AS t
FROM tweets WHERE event_id = XX) AS t1
GROUP BY t
```